# Bootstrap 3 grid mobile view .span6?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I have a issue with my website I have been trying to stack my cards under one and other instead of side by side in mobile view. The issue is if I use .span6 in twitter-bootstrap-3 the card will stretch out I want to keep it at the same proportion. 
I would like to have it the same as the projects selection above.

Website:

https://teamhusky.net/

Example:

[image: Mobile example.]

I would like to stack the members images like the projects.

> 

```css
/*font change*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700);
/**navbar regular*/

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }
}
/*font change*/
h1 {
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}
/*load*/
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.load{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: url(../img/load.gif) center no-repeat #34495e;

}

/*selection tabs*/

.about-tab {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background:#E0E0E0;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.service-tab {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.project-tab {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.members-tab {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.contact-tab {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #fff;
}
/*Google maps responsive*/

.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border: 0;
}


/*hover effect project tab*/

.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    background: #8dd8f8;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}
.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: none;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hovereffect:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.hovereffect h2:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
/*navbar colour*/

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #607d8b;
    border-color: #ffffff;
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #000000;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #000000;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
}
/*Parallax home*/

.ha-bg-parallax {
    background: url("../img/kiruna.JPG") no-repeat fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*typed.js*/
.typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

/*member*/
.profile-card {
background-color: #222222;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.profile-info {
color: #BDBDBD;
padding: 25px;
position: relative;
margin-top: 15px;
}
.profile-info h2 {
color: #E8E8E8;
letter-spacing: 4px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.jobtext{
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
color: #2196F3;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.memlink{
color: #2196F3;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--members start-->
 <section class="members-tab" id="members">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <h1>Members</h1>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="profile-card text-center">
         <div class="profile-info">
          <div class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="1s" data-wow-duration="1s"><img alt="edgaraxe" class="img-responsive" src="https://teamhusky.net/img/edgar.jpg"></div>
          <h2 class="text-center">Edgar Axe</h2>
          <div class="jobtext">
           CEO and Lead Programmer of Team Husky.
          </div>
          <a class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x memlink" href="mailto:edgar@teamhusky.net"></a><br>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="profile-card text-center">
         <div class="profile-info">
          <div class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="2s" data-wow-duration="1s"><img alt="Ahmed" class="img-responsive" src="https://teamhusky.net/img/edgar.jpg"></div>
          <h2 class="text-center">Ahmed</h2>
          <div class="jobtext">
           Chairman of Team Husky.
          </div>
          <a class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x memlink" href="mailto:ahmed@teamhusky.net"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section><!--Members end-->
```

Comment: You don't nest containers. Your markup should be container > row > columns > row > columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've told the markup to render 50% at mobile. Instead of `col-xs-6` you should have `col-xs-12 col-sm-6`.